# How to get current World Time

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

The diffrence between 2 dates - current time and mysql time. This can be backdoored when user change his PC time and the code is Bypassing him from the diffrence check.

I've tried to use

```
mktime()
```

but its not working when my mysql date is `1451094007` (Sat, 26 Dec 2015 01:40:07 GMT) and real world time is for example `1451108407` (Sat, 26 Dec 2015 05:40:07 GMT) 4 hours later, and minimum difference is 10 hours user can still add some hours on him own PC and bypass time.

How can I get any world time which can't be manipulated?

Comment: Use the time on the server!!

Comment: And also set the timezone on the server : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Why is your "mysql date" different from the actual date and time?

Answer (score 1):

You get all timezones using in the world store in array then run in loop

```
foreach($timezonearray as $timezone){

$time = new DateTime($timezone);
   echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

it will print result like this 
http://www.timehubzone.com/worldclock

single way

```
$time = new DateTime('Africa/Abidjan');
   echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

you can get all time zones here
[timezones list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 0):

You can use other services such as http://worldclockapi.com/

(see http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now)

Fetch the result and feed them to variable.

Basically, your application should use the server time where it's hosted (configured with server clock) and `time()` should have respected the server clock